# Partial autocorrelation function - A doubt on a property

Tags: time-series

The PACF of a stationary process $\{x_t\}$, denoted by $\phi_{hh}$ is equal to:

- $\rho(1)$, for $h=1$
- $Corr(x_{t+h}-\hat x_{t+h}, x_{t}-\hat x_{t})$ for $h>1$,
  where $\hat x_{t+h}$ is the OLS regression of $x_{t+h}$ on $\{x_{t+h-1},...,x_{t+1}\}$, and $\hat x_{t}$ is the OLS regression of $x_{t}$ on $\{x_{t+1},...,x_{t+h-1}\}$.(no intercept)

This can be seen as the 'direct' or partial effect of $x_t$ on $x_{t+h}$.

What I don't understand is why should both OLS regressions give the same coefficients(although for different variables).

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "give the same coefficients" and why you believe this is true?

Comment: http://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa3/tsa3.pdf

Page 102, right at the beginning. The authors state that they will deal with this in the next section, but I just don't find it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PACF is usually defined in terms of linear projections.

Suppose we have random variable $Y$, and a set of random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. Then the linear projection of $Y$ on $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random variable $P_{X_1,...,X_n}Y=\alpha_1X_1+...+\alpha_nX_n$, where coefficients $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ minimize the expression:

$$E(Y-\alpha_1X_1-...-\alpha_nX_n)^2.$$

It is not hard to see that the coefficients satisfy the following system of linear equations:

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
EX_1^2 & EX_1X_2 & ...&EX_1X_n\\
... & ... & ... & ...\\
EX_nX_1 & EX_nX_2 & ...& EX_n^2
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_1\\
...\\
\alpha_n
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
EYX_1\\
...\\
EYX_n
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now the partial correlation coefficient is defined for stationary time series $X_t$ as

$$\alpha(k)=corr(X_{k+1}-P_{X_2,...,X_k}X_{k+1}, X_1-P_{X_2,...,X_k}X_{1}).$$

Now try writing the corresponding systems of linear equations for projections $P_{X_2,...X_k}X_{k+1}$ and $P_{X_2,...,X_k}X_1$. Notice that the matrix is the same, because we project on the same set of variables. Also the right hand side vectors will contain the same values but these values will be in a reversed order for different system of equations. Since the matrix is symmetric the solutions will have the same values, but again in a reversed order for different system.

Comment: I understand why the matrix on LHS is the same, but why is the vector on the RHS also the same? for $P_{X_2,...,X_{k}}X_{k+1}$ we have $[E(X_{k+1}X_1),...,E(X_{k+1}X_k)]^T$, while for $P_{X_2,...,X_{k}}X_{1}$ we have $[E(X_{1}X_1),...,E(X_{1}X_k)]^T$

Comment: They are the same because of the stationarity.

Comment: First, I forgot to thank you for your answer. Thanks ;)

Second, let's assume $E(X_t)=0$, by weak stationarity $E(X_tX_{t+k})=\gamma(k)$. In the first case, our RHS is $[\gamma(k-1),...,\gamma(1) ]$, and in the second case our RHS is $[\gamma(1),...,\gamma(k-1) ]$, right? 
I did a mistake in my comment. I should have in $X_2$ instead of $X_1$